# Why we can't concatanate list to dict but can += them in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, typeerror

Why is it that I get "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list" when I do this:

```
print([1,2,3] + {-i:i*i for i in range(3)})
```

But this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a += {-i-1:0 for i in range(3)}
print(a)
```

Runs as it ok and outputs this:

```
[1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3]
```

Comment: Because `+=` is basically `.extend`, and accepts any iterable.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the list prefers the dictionary keys over the dictionary values?

Comment: `a += x` implicitly calls `iter(x)`, and the keys are what the default iterator for a `dict` returns. It's just a design choice. If you wanted the values, you'd have to be explicit: `a += d.values()`.

Comment: @deecue in Python, when a dict is treated as an iterable, it returns its keys. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out the answer so quickly!